# After wipe Apps are still shown as installed on Android's Web Market. How can I install them?

Tags: google-play-store

I accidentally formatted my phone. Now, when I login to my google account it doesn't install my new apps. When I login through internet, it shows in "My Library" that those apps are installed, but they are not. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing is to open each app (even if it says "Installed") and install each one.

Comment: Is it the simplest way?

Comment: It's what I did when I did a factory reset. It gave me an opportunity to decide which apps I really wanted back.